How to detect multiple tasks in a single command using LLM or any NLP model?
I am building a bot that takes inputs from users and performs action. Now I want it to differentiate between commands that contain single task and multiple tasks.
How can I make this a reality? Should I utilize prompting but there are infinite types of commands and infinite ways they can be represented, I doubt if an LLM will be able to comprehend it across all commands.
Or should I train a model or fine-tune an LLM to comprehend it but yet again the dataset would be too big and there will be infinite ways a single command can be represented.
What do you guys suggest I do?
I tried prompting GPT-3.5 with the following:
Carefully, analyze the request for multiple tasks and generate JSON output for all requests in below format:
            When there are multiple tasks:
            {{ 'task': the task, 'type': 'multiple_task' }}
            When there is a single task:
            {{'task': the task, 'type': 'single_task'}}

            ### Example Analysis:

            For the request: "how many executions happen with success and fail so far"

            This is considered a multiple task because it is asking for two distinct counts:
            1. The count of successful executions.
            2. The count of failed executions.

            Therefore, the JSON output for this request should indicate multiple tasks.

            Example JSON output for this request:
            {
                "requests": {{
            'task': 'how many execution happen with success and fail so far',
            'type': 'multiple_task'
            }}
            }
            
            Now do the same for the following user request.
            User request: 

It gives some correct responses but when I send :
When a New google calendar event is created, post a message to general channel in slack plus sync it to Salesforce leads 
It gives me:
{
    "requests": [
        {
            "task": "When a New google calendar event is created, post a message to general channel in slack",
            "type": "single_task"
        },
        {
            "task": "sync it to Salesforce leads",
            "type": "single_task"
        }
    ]
}



I would suggest you identify how many tasks are in each command first, then identify the keyword for each task. According to each keyword perform relevant action:
To identify how many tasks are in each command, parsing the command to each single char. Using some methods, for example, if the command contains keyword like "and", "then", it will likely involve multiple tasks. Then classifying each single char of each task into a group - like:
tokens = command.split()

# create a list to store identified tasks
tasks = []

# (method)

# example
# command = "Do task A and then task B"
# Output: [['Do', 'task', 'A'], ['task', 'B']]

 

Then, label each group(task). You may use machine learning according to your data feature in the step. Finally, perform the relevant actions according to labels.
